# What it the meaning of csrf token?

Tags: django

I am getting this error please haldle the csrf token in django project.When I first made an AJAX call with a POST request, I got a HTTP 403 Forbidden error. A quick debug led me to the CSRF authorisation problem. The backend refused to authorise the request because there is no accompanying CSRF token to prove that the request is not from a foreign site.

Comment: Hello and welcom to SO, have you read this page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/ ?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> "The CSRF middleware and template tag provides easy-to-use
> **protection against Cross Site Request Forgeries**. This type of attack occurs when a malicious website contains a link, a form button
> or some JavaScript that is intended to perform some action on your
> website, using the credentials of a logged-in user who visits the
> malicious site in their browser."

Therefore, when making a POST request, you should always include a CSRF token.

For more information, including how to use it with AJAX calls, please refer to the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/